# Javascript alternative to document.write not innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I modified a little js script which compares a date to today and calculates the difference. (I'm a novice) 
However, it uses document.write, which I've been told is bad. 
I don't know why it's bad, people just say it's bad and never explain why. 
Anyway, I'm looking for an alternative. innerHTML doesn't seem to work, and other questions answered on this site just point to DOM manipulation references without really answering the question.

Here's my script:

```
    //Set the two dates
    var iquit =new Date(2013, 1, 15);
    today=new Date();
    //Get 1 day in milliseconds
    var one_day=1000*60*60*24;
    var day_numeric=Math.ceil((today.getTime()-iquit.getTime())/(one_day));
    //Calculate difference btw the two dates, and convert to days
    document.write("<p>"+day_numeric+
            " days have gone by since you quit smoking!</p>"+
            "<p>You have saved "+ day_numeric*7+" pounds</p>");
```

If anyone can tell me a better way to write this, it'd be amazing.

Comment: The most common solution is to use `innerHTML`. What does "does not work" mean here?

Comment: Haven't seen [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/802943/1169519) yet? It explains, why `document.write` is "bad".

Comment: Thanks for the link to the explanation!
By "Does not work" it does not write to the DOM.

Comment: Both `document.write()` and `innerHTML` should work. Are you sure, that you're not outputting to a hidden / covered element? BTW, the calculation inside of the DW's argument may result `NaN`, it's better to enclose it within parentehes.

Comment: I think you will find this helpful: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners.

Comment: That was not helpful Felix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.write) is that if you call it after the DOM is ready, it will overwrite the existing DOM. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12376186/678801) has a more extensive explanation to why `document.write()` rarely is the best choice.

Using `.innerHTML` should work fine, but you need to select the element you want to add the content do. So something like this:

```
document.getElementById("idOfSomeElement").innerHTML = "your content";
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j5WUp/)

*What method to use to get the proper element depends on what you have to select on, but if possible, the easiest way is probably to attach an ID to the element you want to add content to, and use the above method.*

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I tried this though and had no success.

Comment: @dmc In what way did it not work? Added a link to an example in my answer. Could it be that you are running your code before the DOM is ready? Try moving your code to the end of your body-element, just before the closing body-tag.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, and thank you for explaining the placement.
I'd been running the code in the head, and nothing was being output, no matter what I tried.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using pure JavaScript, one of best ways to get this may be:

```
var paragraph1 = document.createElement("p");
paragraph1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(day_numeric+" days have gone by since you quit smoking!"));

var paragraph2 = document.createElement("p");
paragraph1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("You have saved "+ day_numeric*7+" pounds"));

document.body.appendChild(paragraph1);
document.body.appendChild(paragraph2);
```

100% standard DOM.

#### About document.write: good or evil...

I guess some consider `document.write` as a bad practice because it's the lower-level way of output raw content to the (X)HTML document.

Since (X)HTML is basically a dialect of XML (or at least, based on XML and SGML), the *right* and *expected* way of writing a document is creating nodes and appending them to the whole document.

`document.write` writes the content after the last written element and you lose a lot of control when you want to decide where to place the newly-created element in the document.

For example, would you output a paragraph from a JavaScript function loaded in the from the `<head>` element? It would be hard as it'll not be rendered in the body necessarily. *That's too bad*.

It's better to create DOM elements/nodes and append them to the document using `appendChild(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, but I still cannot get anything to write to the page.

Comment: @dmc But have you created the DOM elements as I suggested in my answer?

Comment: @dmc Didn't played with DOM before?

Comment: A little, I just don't understand your answers, no offence.

Comment: @dmc http://jsfiddle.net/LmDXu/1/ Check how it works in a "live" environment (I mean, the code sample).

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for reasons why it is considered bad practice: [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

And how are you using innerHTML?

Have you tryed something like

```
<script>
...
document.getElementById('container-id').innerHTML = "<p>"+day_numeric+" days have gone by since you quit smoking!</p>"+"<p>You have saved "+ day_numeric*7+" pounds</p>";
</script>
```

This requires an element with the container-id id somewhere in the page, like:

```
<div id='container-id'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this method and it did not write to the page.

Comment: Both innerHTML and the appendChild suggestion from Matías have to work, if they dont its because of some other problem.
Are you sure the javascript code is running? (you can check that in most browsers using console.log("hello world") for instance, or even easier, alert("hello world")). Additionally, are you sure your HTML code has a body? Try using the inspect tool of your browser to check if you are not writting content into the head of the HTML document.