# How do you determine the firing order of load and DOMContentLoaded events?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Why does the below code ([JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/qizaroliwaqo/1/edit)) fire in the order 1, 5, 3, 4? And why does 2 not fire at all?

According to [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12376186/1354989), "4" should fire before "5". That's not what is shown by the order of the alerts. However, if I change the body and img onload handlers to execute `document.write` instead of `alert`, then 5 will be displayed, which is consistent with that answer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
          alert("1");
        });
        document.addEventListener("load", function() {
          alert("2");
        });
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
          alert("3");
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="alert('4')">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <img onload="alert('5')" src="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/redesign/img/logo_sprite.svg?2014-01" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

window/body onload fires after all the images are loaded.

From [MDN window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload#Notes)

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

So window load should come after the image load is fired.

And order of window/body events being triggeed depends on when you register the event listeners

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
          console.log("Head - DOMContentLoaded");
        });
        document.addEventListener("load", function() {
          console.log("head - document load");
        });
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
          console.log("head - window load");
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="console.log('BODY ONLOAD')">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <img onload="console.log('IMG ONLOAD')" src="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/redesign/img/logo_sprite.svg?2014-01" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" />

      <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
          console.log("END - DOMContentLoaded");
        });
        document.addEventListener("load", function() {
          console.log("END - document load");
        });
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
          console.log("END - window load");
        });
      </script>      
    </body>
</html>
```

would result in

- "Head - DOMContentLoaded"
- "END - DOMContentLoaded"
- "IMG ONLOAD"
- "head - window load"
- "BODY ONLOAD"
- "END - window load"

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vadiyogaceye/1/edit?html,console,output)

And not all browsers support document.load.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the thorough example. I understand the logic here, but the thing that still puzzles me is if I change the console.log or alert to document.write, then order of execution appears to change. Is this because if I stick a document.write into the img onload handler, then that will rewrite the document and destroy all the other handlers?

Comment: alert is a "blocking" event which will block the execution thread which will change how things behave. That is why people recommend not using alert to debug.