# Troubles making styling off cards reference javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got troubles making a styling for an array,

Here is my code:

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="card.js"></script>
<script src="Deck.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="card.css">
</head>
<body onload = "addCard()">
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my first JavaScript file with the array (Deck) which refers to my second JavaScript file with the card:

```
var Deck = new Array();
function addCard(){
Deck[0] = new Card("test");
Deck[1] = new Card("1234");
}
```

Here is my second JavaScript file with the card:

```
class Card{
constructor(myText){
document.write("<div class = \"card\">");
document.write("<div class = \"back\">");
document.write("<div class = \"up\"><\/div>");
document.write("<div class=\"down\"><\/div>");
document.write("<hr class = \"arrowUpLeft\">");
document.write("<hr class = \"arrowDownRight\">");
document.write("<hr class = \"arrowUpRight\">");
document.write("<hr class = \"arrowDownLeft\">");
document.write("<div class = \"front\">");
document.write("<p id =\"text_card\">");
document.write(myText);
document.write("<\/p>");
document.write("<\/div>");
document.write("<\/div>");
document.write("<\/div>");
}
}
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.card{
    height: 336px;
    width: 240px;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100%;
}

.card:hover > .back{
    animation: cardturn 1s;
    background-color: blue;
}

.card:hover>.back :not(.front), .card:hover>.back :not(.front)>*{
    animation: cardturn 1s;
    animation: setvisibilityBackInvisible 1s;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.card:hover>.back>.front, .card:hover>.back>.front>*{
    animation: setvisibilityBackVisible 1s;
    visibility: visible;
}

.back{
    height: 328px;
    width: 232px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius:46px;
    z-index: 2;
    border: 4px solid black;
    animation: cardturn2 1s;
}

.front, .front>*{
    animation: setvisibilityBackInvisible 1s;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.back>:not(.front), .back>:not(.front)>*{
    animation: setvisibilityBackVisible 1s;
    visibility: visible;
}

.up{
    position: relative;
    top: 114px;
    left: 66px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid blue;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.down{
    position: relative;
    top: 114px;
    left: 66px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid blue;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.arrowUpLeft{
    position: relative;
    top: -22px;
    left:-25px;
    width: 214px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.arrowDownRight{
    position: relative;
    top: 118px;
    left:25px;
    width: 214px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.arrowUpRight{
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    left:-25px;
    width: 70px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.arrowDownLeft{
    position: relative;
    top: 44px;
    left:25px;
    width: 70px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    border: 2px solid black;
}

@keyframes cardturn{
    0%,100%{
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    50%{
        transform: scale(0,1);
        background-color: red;
    }
    51%{
        background-color: blue;
    }
    0%{
        background-color: red;
    }
    100%{
        background-color:blue;
    }
}

@keyframes cardturn2{
    0%,100%{
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    50%{
        transform: scale(0,1);
        background-color: blue;
    }
    51%{
        background-color: red;
    }
    100%{
        background-color: red;
    }
    0%{
        background-color: blue;
    }
}

@keyframes cardturn3{
    0%,100%{
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    50%{
        transform: scale(0,1);
    }
}

@keyframes setvisibilityBackInvisible{
    0%,50%{
        visibility: visible;
    }
    51%,100%{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

@keyframes setvisibilityBackVisible{
    0%,50%{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    100%{
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me guys, I would thank you very much. Even if you could just only explain why the CSS doesn't work could explain I actually would be very happy, because I then know what to do.

Comment: **What is your problem and what is your question** ? You've pretty much said, "here is the code I have, I hope you can help" Help with what? Please be direct, specific and clear. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the spaces:

```
"<div class = \"card\">"
```

Should be:

```
"<div class=\"card\">"
```

Comment: Is this makes any sense, what are you trying to do

Comment: Thanks for your help, now I think I can get to work on

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering your function on [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) `<body onload="addCard()">`.
I think that it could be that when you use [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) at that time, the document has been closed and it will automatically calls `document.open`, which will [clear the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open#Notes).

For more information, you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376100/document-write-method-questions).

Maybe instead of using `document.write`, you can create an element using [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and add your html.

**Note** that you are duplicating the id's `<p id =\"text_card\">`

```js
class Card {
    constructor(myText) {
        var elm = document.createElement('div');
        elm.setAttribute('class', "card");

        var html = '<div class = "back">';
        html += '<div class = "up"></div>';
        html += '<div class="down"></div>';
        html += '<hr class = "arrowUpLeft">';
        html += '<hr class = "arrowDownRight">';
        html += '<hr class = "arrowUpRight">';
        html += '<hr class = "arrowDownLeft">';
        html += '<div class = "front">';
        html += '<p id ="text_card">';
        html += myText;
        html += "</p>";
        html += "</div>";
        html += "</div>";

        elm.innerHTML = html;
        document.body.appendChild(elm);
    }
}

var Deck = new Array();

function addCard() {
    Deck[0] = new Card("test");
    Deck[1] = new Card("1234");
}
```

```css
.card{
    height: 336px;
    width: 240px;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100%;
}

.card:hover > .back{
    animation: cardturn 1s;
    background-color: blue;
}

.card:hover>.back :not(.front), .card:hover>.back :not(.front)>*{
    animation: cardturn 1s;
    animation: setvisibilityBackInvisible 1s;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.card:hover>.back>.front, .card:hover>.back>.front>*{
    animation: setvisibilityBackVisible 1s;
    visibility: visible;
}

.back{
    height: 328px;
    width: 232px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius:46px;
    z-index: 2;
    border: 4px solid black;
    animation: cardturn2 1s;
}

.front, .front>*{
    animation: setvisibilityBackInvisible 1s;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.back>:not(.front), .back>:not(.front)>*{
    animation: setvisibilityBackVisible 1s;
    visibility: visible;
}

.up{
    position: relative;
    top: 114px;
    left: 66px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid blue;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.down{
    position: relative;
    top: 114px;
    left: 66px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid blue;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.arrowUpLeft{
    position: relative;
    top: -22px;
    left:-25px;
    width: 214px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.arrowDownRight{
    position: relative;
    top: 118px;
    left:25px;
    width: 214px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.arrowUpRight{
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    left:-25px;
    width: 70px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.arrowDownLeft{
    position: relative;
    top: 44px;
    left:25px;
    width: 70px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    border: 2px solid black;
}

@keyframes cardturn{
    0%,100%{
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    50%{
        transform: scale(0,1);
        background-color: red;
    }
    51%{
        background-color: blue;
    }
    0%{
        background-color: red;
    }
    100%{
        background-color:blue;
    }
}

@keyframes cardturn2{
    0%,100%{
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    50%{
        transform: scale(0,1);
        background-color: blue;
    }
    51%{
        background-color: red;
    }
    100%{
        background-color: red;
    }
    0%{
        background-color: blue;
    }
}

@keyframes cardturn3{
    0%,100%{
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    50%{
        transform: scale(0,1);
    }
}

@keyframes setvisibilityBackInvisible{
    0%,50%{
        visibility: visible;
    }
    51%,100%{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

@keyframes setvisibilityBackVisible{
    0%,50%{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    100%{
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="card.js"></script>
<script src="Deck.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="card.css">
</head>
<body onload = "addCard()">
</body>
</html>
```